# Notice: unserialize(); Error at offset in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento-2.1, fatal-error, setup-di-compile, magento2.2, magento2.2.0

This code not working in Magento 2.2, But it's working in Magento 2.1. I am facing this error

> Notice: unserialize(); Error at offset 0 of 168 bytes in /var/www/html/M2/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/MyBlock.php

```
$infoRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_all')->getValue();
$addtoCartreqest = unserialize($infoRequest);
```

Comment: use `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` instead of direct unserialize values

Comment: Can you explain in details with answer

Comment: Magento 2.2 does not use serialization any more. In most palaces it's replaced with JSON format. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html

Answer (score 25):

Inject `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json` class for serialize and unserialize values.

```
protected $serialize;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize,
    ...
) {
    $this->serialize = $serialize;
}
```

Now use `$this->serialize`

```
 $value = $this->serialize->unserialize($serializeData);
```

**As per Magento 2.2 Release Note**

> Security enhancements
>
> In general, we’ve removed serialize/unserialize from most the code to improve protection against remote code execution attacks. We’ve enhanced protection of code where use of object serialization or unserialization was unavoidable. Additionally, we’ve increased our use of output escaping to protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.