# Magento 2.2.0 : Add to cart product error unable to unserialize value

Tags: error, addtocart, magento2.2.0

I have create gift card product types and add custom options like this

1. Choose Amount:Card value
2. select a design:
3. compose your email :

   ```
      To :

        Recipient Name
        Recipient Email

      Form :

        Sender Name
        Sender Email
   ```
4. Headline:
5. Message:
6. Date to send:
7. Time Zone

I added product into add to cart But, product is not update `mini cart` and `checkout/cart` page display error like this :

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
>        #0 vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/Configuration.php(118): Magento\Framework \Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize.

How to solve this type issue?

I tried the answers from "[Magento 2.2 error: Unable to unserialize value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196216/magento-2-2-error-unable-to-unserialize-value)" but this is not working.

---

[image]

Comment: i have already used this link but not working @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: Try to debug from where this error comes (in backend). Check is taht error are reproducing when all third-party modules are disabled.

Comment: now i am use magento 2.2.0 fresh version. @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i have got the solution.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
    public function getUnserializeData($data)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $version = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface')->getVersion();
        if($version >= '2.2.0'){
            $returnData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface')->unserialize($data);
        }
        else{

            $returnData = (array) unserialize($data);
        }

        return $returnData;     
    }
    public function getSerializeData($data)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $version = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface')->getVersion();
        if($version >= '2.2.0'){
            $returnData = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface')->serialize($data);
        }
        else{

            $returnData = serialize($data);
        }
        return $returnData;     
    }
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php

```
        $additionalOptions = [];
        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {

            $additionalOptions = $this->_helper->getUnserializeData($additionalOption->getValue());
        }


       if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            $item->addOption([
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => $this->_helper->getSerializeData($additionalOptions)
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: my magento version is 2.2.5 but its not work. any other solution?

Comment: It could be better with dependency injection. 
It is a good answer though. Upvote from my side :)