# Magento add Image Slider getting unserialize(): Error

Tags: php, magento2.2, widgets, banner-slider

I have tried to add Image Slider into my home page using following the steps using the following link
https://magenticians.com/customize-homepage-magento-2-add-image-slider/

When I clicked save after configuring the things, I an gettting an error

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1208 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Ves\Productlist\Model\Magento\Widget\Instance.php on line 35
```

[image: Image Slider Error]

Please llok instance.php code below

```
class Instance extends \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Instance
{
    /**
     * Getter
     * Unserialize if serialized string setted
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWidgetParameters()
    {

        if (is_string($this->getData('widget_parameters'))) {
            $params = unserialize($this->getData('widget_parameters'));

            $field_pattern = ["pretext","pretext_html","shortcode","html","raw_html","content","tabs","latestmod_desc","custom_css","block_params"];
            $widget_types = ["Ves\BaseWidget\Block\Widget\Accordionbg"];

            $is_custom_params = false;

            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                if(0 < strpos($k, 'class') || 0 < strpos($k, 'Class')) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(is_array($params[$k]) || !$this->isBase64Encoded($params[$k])) {
                    if(in_array($k, $field_pattern) || preg_match("/^tabs(.*)/", $k) || preg_match("/^content_(.*)/", $k) || (preg_match("/^header_(.*)/", $k) && in_array($type, $widget_types))) {
                        if(is_array($params[$k])){
                            $params[$k] = base64_encode(serialize($params[$k]));
                        }elseif(!$this->isBase64Encoded($params[$k])){
                            $params[$k] = base64_encode($params[$k]);
                        }
                        $is_custom_params = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            if($is_custom_params) {
                $this->setData('widget_parameters', $params);
            }

        }

        return parent::getWidgetParameters();
    }
    public function isBase64Encoded($data) {
        if(base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am new to Magento. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Share/Copy `app\code\Ves\Productlist\Model\Magento\Widget\Instance.php` file in your question I will help you.

Comment: @PrincePatel updated the question with the code, please check it

Comment: In Magento 2.2 you cannot direct __unserialize__ value. You should first construct an object. Refer my answer for how use unserialize: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/195302/35758

Comment: @PrincePatel I am new to php please guide me how can i solve this issue. post as an answer i will accept.

Comment: You should accept an answer to help other developers to find their right solution

Answer (score 0):

Your final code like this:

> app\code\Ves\Productlist\Model\Magento\Widget\Instance.php

```
class Instance extends \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Instance
{
    protected $serialize;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize
    ) {
        $this->serialize = $serialize;
    }

    /**
     * Getter
     * Unserialize if serialized string setted
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getWidgetParameters()
    {

        if (is_string($this->getData('widget_parameters'))) {
            $params = $this->serialize->unserialize($this->getData('widget_parameters'));

            $field_pattern = ["pretext","pretext_html","shortcode","html","raw_html","content","tabs","latestmod_desc","custom_css","block_params"];
            $widget_types = ["Ves\BaseWidget\Block\Widget\Accordionbg"];

            $is_custom_params = false;

            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                if(0 < strpos($k, 'class') || 0 < strpos($k, 'Class')) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(is_array($params[$k]) || !$this->isBase64Encoded($params[$k])) {
                    if(in_array($k, $field_pattern) || preg_match("/^tabs(.*)/", $k) || preg_match("/^content_(.*)/", $k) || (preg_match("/^header_(.*)/", $k) && in_array($type, $widget_types))) {
                        if(is_array($params[$k])){
                            $params[$k] = base64_encode(serialize($params[$k]));
                        }elseif(!$this->isBase64Encoded($params[$k])){
                            $params[$k] = base64_encode($params[$k]);
                        }
                        $is_custom_params = true;
                    }
                }

            }
            if($is_custom_params) {
                $this->setData('widget_parameters', $params);
            }

        }

        return parent::getWidgetParameters();
    }
    public function isBase64Encoded($data) {
        if(base64_encode(base64_decode($data)) === $data){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Now remove \var and \generated folder.**