# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 94 bytes Magento 2.2.5 when update wishlist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

I am getting an error `{"0":"Notice: unserialize():` Error at offset 0 of 94 bytes in. `\Model\Item.php` When update wishlist from wishlist page. I am using Magento 2.2.5

I already try this solution and this solution worked for add all cart from wishlist. but not working when update list.

Tried solution Link: [Notice: unserialize(); Error at offset in Magento 2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195300/notice-unserialize-error-at-offset-in-magento-2-2/195302)

Answer (score 0):

It might be because values of array got corrupted. You can use this though

```
//to serialize array/string
$arrayvalue = base64_encode(serialize($multidimensional_array));

//to unserialize encoded array/string
$getoriginalarrayvalue = unserialize(base64_decode($arrayvalue));
```

Comment: Not working  mY code is  foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['code'] == 'info_buyRequest') {
                $optionValue = $this->serializer->unserialize(trim($option['value']));

                $optionValue['qty'] = $qty;
                $unserializeOption['value'] = $optionValue;

Comment: I also used you code but not worling